# Background slider

Tags: html, css, magento, background, slider

I have a slider on my homepage with.

I made a background, but it isn't the at the top. Now it's under my slide items. How can make sure that the background is upper than the slide items? Something with `z-index`?

Comment: seems to be working fine in chrome? Could you post the html / a jsfiddle as an example?

Answer (score 1):

if your "background is this one: [IMAGE](http://magento.gaafwebdesign.nl//skin/frontend/rwd/shop/images/sliderbg.png) it will never show as you have put the image as `background-image` in the slider container so obviously the images inside that container will show on top.

What you need to do is to add in your html a div inside `id="slider"` right before the `id="prevBtn" span` like this one:

```
<div class="border-image"></div>
```

and add this css:

```
.slider4_effect {position:relative;}
.border-image {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-image:url('http://magento.gaafwebdesign.nl//skin/frontend/rwd/shop/images/sliderbg.png'); /*or your relative path*/
    background-size:cover
}
```

that should work fine

Comment: Thanks for reply. I want this image as background: http://www.drawingforkids.org/images/131987-quality-vintage-wallpaper-backgrounds-wallpaper-background-by-click.jpg

You see the litle flowers on the left and right side, those flowers must be at the front/top/upperest of te sliders. So the sliders are on second place and the flowers on the first place.

How can I do that?